# How do I derive Copy when using #![no_std]?

Tags: rust

I am working on a project that uses `#![no_std]`, and I would like to be able to derive useful traits such as `Copy` and `Clone`. I tried adding `pub use core::prelude::*;` to both the project root, and the file I actually want to use it in. However, any attempts to `#[derive(Copy)]` results in

> error: attempt to implement a nonexistent trait std::marker::Copy

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Attempting to add

```
use core::marker::Copy
```

yields this:

> error: a type named Copy has already been imported in this module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always implement marker traits with `impl`:

```
impl Copy for MyStruct {}
```

It will work only for marker traits though, `Clone` and other similar traits still need `deriving`.

Comment: what's a marker trait, and why don't you need to provide an actual impl?

Comment: Marker traits do not contain methods and exist solely for the purpose of marking types with some property. For example, `Copy` means that the type is automatically copyable; `Send` means that the type is sendable across task boundaries, etc. Since they have no methods, they don't have anything to implement, so their impl block is empty.

Answer (score 3):

#[derive] is broken in #![no_std] `pub mod std {pub use core::*;}` will fix it, it replaces instances of `::std::` with `::core::` allowing you to derive traits that the compiler thinks are in `std` from `core`

Comment: Is this expected behavior, or is there a Rust bug you could link to?

Comment: @Shepmaster, I believe this happens because `derive`s are just AST transformations, just what compiler plugins do, so they have to specify full names in identifiers. In most programs it's `std` what is linked by default, not `core`, so they use `::std`. However, i don't know if there is an open ticket on that.

Comment: I'm not sure either,  a couple people in the IRC mentioned it though